# Unanswered Questions - Clean Up

Tags: discussion, feature-request, unanswered-questions

Since I was free, I went on a spree of visiting unanswered question in the last one year and trying to answer them.

**Problem**: There are few questions like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984094/cmd-on-vba-code-error-this-object-does-not-support-this-property-or-method) where the user did manage to find an answer but didn't bother to post a solution back even when insisted by another member. And I say "Didn't bother" because in the profile of that user, it clearly shows that the user logged in later (Oct 9, 2013).

**Question** What do we do?

1. Post an answer if we know it?
2. Flag the question? If yes, then which flag?

**Unrelated Question:** Do such questions (and I am sure there are plenty cross stack sites) take lot of space? If yes, then would deleting them be a good idea? If yes, then can we get a `Delete Option` so we can vote such questions to be deleted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answering questions that the OP already knows the answer to

Post an answer if you know one (assuming you think the question will be of use to others), answers aren't primarily for the question asker; they're for the internet in general. After all stack exchange's [mission](https://stackexchange.com/about) is;

> Stack Exchange is a growing network of individual communities, each
> dedicated to serving experts in a specific field. **We build libraries
> of high-quality questions and answers**, focused on each community's
> area of expertise.

The presence or absence of the OP is ultimately irrelevant to this

#### Deleting old questions

Old unanswered questions are deleted automatically under [certain circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006), downvote if you feel the question isn't a good question, otherwise there is no need to do anything else (unless you have other concerns); the automated script will take care of it

Comment: Fair enough. That partly answers my first question. I have 2 questions though based on your post. `1` If I don't know the answer and the question is too old? or `2` I feel it is of no use to future visitors. Then voting to delete (if allowed) them would be a good idea?

Comment: See my updated answer for that. But its worth remembering; disk space is insanely cheap, moderator time (to answer flags) is precious

Comment: Super! That is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find it. Perhaps I was searching using the wrong keywords. Thanks again.

Comment: I ended up answering the question. Thanks for the advice again :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Glad to hear it all worked out